# gerrit query doesn't print PL

Tags: gerrit

```
ssh -p 29418 review.test.com gerrit query --patch-sets 199423
```

This prints most of the fields I see in gerrit page but not the `PL`, I see `PL` in gerrit page, is there a way to make the gerrit query print the same? I am new to gerrit, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If by PL you mean the rules.pl file you can't get that by using gerrit query.

You can download and edit the config for your project by using Git commands:

```
git fetch origin refs/meta/config:config
git checkout config
... edit or create the rules.pl file
git add rules.pl
git commit -m "My submit rules"
git push origin HEAD:refs/meta/config
```

[Documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/prolog-cookbook.html#RulesFile)